# Imagemagick adding and reading comment

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to add a comment to an image using imagemagick and read it back
For adding a comment i can do

```
convert -comment "processed" original.jpg converted.jpg
```

Now the output of identify -verbose converted.jpeg

```
Properties:
comment: processed
date:create: 2017-05-17T12:22:36+06:00
date:modify: 2017-05-17T12:22:36+06:00
exif:ColorSpace: 1
exif:DateTime: 2017:02:04 12:21:36
exif:ExifImageLength: 1273
exif:ExifImageWidth: 900
exif:ExifOffset: 164
exif:Orientation: 1
exif:ResolutionUnit: 2
exif:Software: Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows
exif:thumbnail:Compression: 6
exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 302
exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 3805
exif:thumbnail:ResolutionUnit: 2
exif:thumbnail:XResolution: 300/1
exif:thumbnail:YResolution: 300/1
```

Is there a cleaner way to read back the comments other than

```
identify -verbose converted.jpg | grep 'comment'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can *set* the comment like this:

```
convert YourImage.jpg -set comment "fred" YourImage.jpg
```

or, it's probably better to use `mogrify` to avoid repeating yourself in this instance:

```
mogrify -set comment "bill" YourImage.jpg
```

And that technique allows you to do multiple images at once:

```
mogrify -set comment "bill" *.jpg
```

---

You can *extract* just the comment like this:

```
identify -format %c YourImage.jpg 
fred
```

---

im4java - I have no knowledge of im4java, but can only guess (based on [this](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html)) that you would do:

```
 Info imageInfo = new Info(filename,true);
 System.out.println("Format: " + imageInfo.getImageComment());
```

Alternatively, maybe you can build your own `ConvertCmd`knowing that the following `convert` works at the command line if you don't know how to make an `identify` command in `im4java`:

```
convert -format %c YourImage.jpg info:
```